# java.lang.AbstractMethodError when adding Header to Java 4 JAX-RPC SOAP Handler

Tags: soap, handlers, jax-rpc, java1.4

I have to write a JAX-RPC SOAP message Handler in Java 4, and I need to add a security header to the message.

At present, when I try to send a message I get a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeader.addHeaderElement(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPHeaderElement;` error.

I can't find much online for this error, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is below:

```
public final boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) {
    SOAPMessageContext soapContext = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
    String authId = "test";
        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = soapContext.getMessage();
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();
            /* If no header, add one */
            if (soapHeader == null) {
                soapHeader = soapEnv.addHeader();
            }

            /* Add a soap header, name as AUTH_ID_KEY */
            QName qname = new QName(TARGET_NAMESPACE, AUTH_ID_KEY);
            SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(qname);
            soapHeaderElement.addTextNode(authId);
            soapMsg.saveChanges();
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            throw new ProtocolException(e);
        }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeader` implements `javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader`but keeps the `addHeaderElement(QName)` method abstract.

When using this implementation then, I had to use the `addHeaderElement(javax.xml.soap.Name)` method instead.

The final working code is below:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapContext.getMessage();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
/* If no header, add one */
if (soapHeader == null) {
    soapHeader = soapEnvelope.addHeader();
}

/* Add a soap header, name as AUTH_ID_KEY */
Name name = soapEnvelope.createName(AUTH_ID_KEY);
SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(name);
soapHeaderElement.addTextNode(authId);
soapMessage.saveChanges();
```